# CSS not called from header.php

Tags: php, html, css

I had some big problems calling my header at all from project1.php. It got solved with the header included like this:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
```

The header is now called, but all my CSS is not called. Howcome can that be? On all my pages there is lying in the root folder the CSS is working fine.

**My folder structure is looking like this:**

[image: Folder structure]

This code below is a snip of my header. As you can see Home should go to index.php. But when I am in my project1.php and I click on Home I get the URL: `

> http://localhost:8888/vouzalis/projects/index.php

The correct root should be:

> http://localhost:8888/vouzalis/index.php

It does not make sense to be. Does anybody have a clue why? Is it something with how the header is included?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main pull-right">
        <!-- begin navigation items -->
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="services_smallicon.php">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="aboutme.php">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <!-- end navigation items -->
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: you'd need to show the generated html. the php by itself is useless. and your sample urls are useless, since they only work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

Replace `href="index.php"` with `href="/vouzalis/index.php"`. The `/` specifies the domain root, without it, the root is the your current location (`/vouzalis/projects/`).

Comment: Make sense of course. Thank you a lot, it is working now :-)